# Lubuntu: Wifi lose connection

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic
```

kernel

```
    Linux 3.16.0-31-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 17:37:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7
```

desktop

```
Lubuntu
```

lspci

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0642]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0936]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

rfkill

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lsmod

```
ath9k                 136984  0 
ath9k_common           25638  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              446568  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    29052  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              660592  1 ath9k
cfg80211              510218  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
acer_wmi               32522  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 acer_wmi
ath3k                  13331  0 
bluetooth             446190  23 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
snd_soc_rt5640         93042  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         13037  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          200204  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_pcm               104102  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
wmi                    19193  1 acer_wmi
video                  20128  2 i915,acer_wmi
```

interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:10.7.0.181  Bcast:10.7.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::aeb5:7dff:fe94:f2de/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:31423 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:16554964 (16.5 MB)  TX bytes:2307140 (2.3 MB)
```

iwconfig

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=6.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:161  Invalid misc:1952   Missed beacon:0
```

route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.7.0.254      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.7.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

nm-tool

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0  [FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f] 
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           6 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    Phil13:          Infra, <MAC 'Phil13' [AC3]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 95 WPA2
    vodafoneFVKJ:    Infra, <MAC 'vodafoneFVKJ' [AC2]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 55 WPA2
    Namaste Nepal:   Infra, <MAC 'Namaste Nepal' [AC4]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 74 WPA2
    WirelessNation_D935: Infra, <MAC 'WirelessNation_D935' [AC7]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA2
    Zest 523:        Infra, <MAC 'Zest 523' [AN5]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA WPA2
    Nepal:           Infra, <MAC 'Nepal' [AC10]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 50 WPA2
    KIARA:           Infra, <MAC 'KIARA' [AC9]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 82 WPA2
    The Real Gurkhas:Infra, <MAC 'The Real Gurkhas' [AC11]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 50 WPA2
    AKL ON:          Infra, <MAC 'AKL ON' [AN9]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70
    *FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f: Infra, <MAC 'FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f' [AC1]>, Freq 2447 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 53
    KTN:             Infra, <MAC 'KTN' [AN11]>, Freq 2447 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 44 WPA WPA2
    Connect@625:     Infra, <MAC 'Connect@625' [AC5]>, Freq 2447 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 42 WPA WPA2
    SPARK-GZ6JWP:    Infra, <MAC 'SPARK-GZ6JWP' [AN13]>, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 44 WPA WPA2
    Santino07:       Infra, <MAC 'Santino07' [AN14]>, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 52 WPA2
    SteveZacTyrone:  Infra, <MAC 'SteveZacTyrone' [AN15]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 42 WPA WPA2
    VodafoneFibre:   Infra, <MAC 'VodafoneFibre' [AN16]>, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 45 WPA WPA2
    Sarah Wifi:      Infra, <MAC 'Sarah Wifi' [AN17]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA2
    NETGEAR40:       Infra, <MAC 'NETGEAR40' [AN18]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA2
    green house :    Infra, <MAC 'green house ' [AN19]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.7.0.181
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.7.0.254

    DNS:             10.7.0.254
```

NetworkManager.state

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
```

NetworkManager.conf

```
    [main]
    plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
    dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

NetworkManager profiles

```
[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2c]] (600 root)
[connection] id=FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2c | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2c | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f]] (600 root)
[connection] id=FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto
```

iw reg get

```
'iw' is not installed (package "iw").
```

iwlist channels

```
eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
```

iwlist scan

```
Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      3   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
      4   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.467 GHz (Channel 12)

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f' [AC1]>
                    Channel:8
                    Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
                    Quality=41/70  Signal level=-69 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000000a0ec7b4
                    Extra: Last beacon: 880ms ago
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'vodafoneFVKJ' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"vodafoneFVKJ"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000004485eedebb
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'Phil13' [AC3]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Phil13"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001a37b99eab
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1336ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'Namaste Nepal' [AC4]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Namaste Nepal"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000067dc0fd6ed
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1968ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'Connect@625' [AC5]>
                    Channel:8
                    Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Connect@625"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000115118da19b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1064ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'Thomson23A634' [AC6]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Thomson23A634"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000354db40175
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1004ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC 'WirelessNation_D935' [AC7]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"WirelessNation_D935"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000b8fe29ae8d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 08 - Address: <MAC 'shermaine' [AC8]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"shermaine"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000514dac56b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1240ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 09 - Address: <MAC 'KIARA' [AC9]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"KIARA"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000017ccf1c18f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 368ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 10 - Address: <MAC 'Nepal' [AC10]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Nepal"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000562d81446f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 11 - Address: <MAC 'The Real Gurkhas' [AC11]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"The Real Gurkhas"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000006168454b46
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 12 - Address: <MAC 'Zeher' [AC12]>
                    Channel:12
                    Frequency:2.467 GHz (Channel 12)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Zeher"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000be3d054ac
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 13 - Address: <MAC 'RAVINDER' [AC13]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"RAVINDER"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000016dae8d19b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 340ms ago
             lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

module infos

```
[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     5C1878F185424DB0329389D
depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        8F:62:79:8D:54:61:C9:EE:0E:18:3A:ED:94:93:38:E3:EA:18:89:46
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     265A5990B1258ECC29235FC
depends:        cfg80211,ath9k_hw,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        8F:62:79:8D:54:61:C9:EE:0E:18:3A:ED:94:93:38:E3:EA:18:89:46
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     0D1161FC3B202FBE214F25D
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        8F:62:79:8D:54:61:C9:EE:0E:18:3A:ED:94:93:38:E3:EA:18:89:46
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     165C1DF76AF8C8B6A45DA4F
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        8F:62:79:8D:54:61:C9:EE:0E:18:3A:ED:94:93:38:E3:EA:18:89:46
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     D0CBADABD6F74A53B0BE7CC
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        8F:62:79:8D:54:61:C9:EE:0E:18:3A:ED:94:93:38:E3:EA:18:89:46
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     88153DA7841870E4F2012EE
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        8F:62:79:8D:54:61:C9:EE:0E:18:3A:ED:94:93:38:E3:EA:18:89:46
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[ath3k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
license:        GPL
version:        1.0
description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     F6EB9B4BD50E1F5EB2462B2
depends:        bluetooth
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        8F:62:79:8D:54:61:C9:EE:0E:18:3A:ED:94:93:38:E3:EA:18:89:46
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
```

module parameters

```
[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00
```

/etc/modules

modprobe options

```
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/libpisock9.conf]
blacklist visor

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1
```

udev rules

```
[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x168c:0x0036 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

dmesg

```
[   17.041375] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   17.045958] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[   17.045964] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x65
[   17.045966] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   17.045969] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   17.045971] ath: Regpair used: 0x65
[   28.373348] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   61.653910] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f' [AC1]>
[   61.664928] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   61.666898] wlan0: authenticated
[   61.669865] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   61.678303] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f' [AC1]> (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=4)
[   61.678373] wlan0: associated
[   61.678415] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  107.905008] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f' [AC1]>
[  107.912269] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  107.914226] wlan0: authenticated
[  107.917727] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  107.928113] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'FreedomInternet@Zest-Lv2f' [AC1]> (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=4)
[  107.928291] wlan0: associated
```

Comment: First thing I would do is change the channel the wifi router is on to 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, or 10

Comment: I have found out, that when I try reconnect after connection is lost like it's a hidden network, it's connects again. But on Windows all worked fine.